# ASP.NET Core Web API upload and download file

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, download, upload, azure-blob-storage

## My scenario:

- ASP.NET Core 2.1
- Web API Controller
- Azure Blob Storage as storage

I read some docs on internet (and on Stack Overflow in particular), but I didn't find a real complete answer to my question.

## Question

Which is the best practice to upload and download **BIG** files using a ASP.NET Core 2.1 Web Api Controller and Azure Blob Storage as back-end for saving data?

Please, suppose the controller is:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class UploadDownloadController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet("upload")]
    public void Download()
    {
        ...
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public Result Upload([FromBody] string someData)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Where `Result` is a class to return some data on the operation.

Please note that:

- For **BIG** files, it's better not to use `IFormFile` interface
- Files can be very big: tens or hundreds giga

Thank you,

Attilio

Comment: You'll want to look into MultipartReader() and UploadFromStreamAsync() methods for ASP.NET and Azure respectively.

Comment: https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/cloud/platform-as-a-service/azure-blob-storage-part-4-uploading-large-blobs/